# Best choice for replacing old computers for logo printing?

Tags: logo

I want to replace my old computers for my logo designing company but I don't know what would be the best choices for them, specification wise. If possible I would like to compare the cost of new computers,comparing the major features found on system units, at three different price levels: less than $1000 USD; $1,000 to $1,500 USD; and greater than $1,500 USD. What would the major features of the system units at the various price levels be and which computer would you recommend?

Comment: What operating system are you planning to work on?

Comment: I was planning to work on Windows.

Comment: Would you consider building your own or buying a pre-built computer?

Comment: Buying a pre-built computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because any answers would pretty much be *purely* opinion-based. In addition, there are a number of questions already which address upgrading and hardware. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-recommendation

Comment: possible duplicate of [What computer hardware matters to a graphic designer?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17151/what-computer-hardware-matters-to-a-graphic-designer)

Answer (score 1):

You're not providing much detail in your question with your intended goals so i will provide some ideas.

Based on the title "for logo printing" i would imagine you're looking at getting a rip station to possibly print your logo design.  If you're doing that i would consider looking into getting a used dell or hp workstation from a reputable supplier.  There is even a company that builds custom PCs for sign companies called Signburst.

If you are starting out I would probably recommend building your own for the price point you're considering but as I've read you dont seem like you want to try that.

Now, this next piece I recommend because ive ran both but i would suggest going to a mac site that sells used macs like macsales.com or checkout macs refurbished online store.  For the budget you're looking at you can easily buy a used macbook pro and if the RAM isnt soldiered (think thats pre 2013 but not sure) you can max it out with 16gb crucial RAM and a 400gb+ OWC SSD drive that MacSales sales.  I even believe in the checkout process you can order everything and they will install it for you.  If starting out your laptop could be portable and you can always use thunderbolt and run a second monitor or run clamshell (closed laptop) with an external monitor of your choosing.

Just some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to spend more than $1,000 for a graphic design computer unless you're doing some heavy 3D rendering or video editing.

Basically I would look for something along the lines of
- Intel Core i5 or i7 (If they are 3rd generation then they are better)
- 8 gb ram
- A graphics card equivalent GTX 750 or up

at $850 [Dell XPS X8700-1253BLK Desktop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00F5UCIFU)

at $1000 [Acer Predato](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883101018&cm_re=desktop-_-83-101-018-_-Product)

at $1300 [HP Pavilion HPE h8-1360t](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008LDOO6O)

at $1500 [INTEL Core i7 4770 3.4Ghz 8Gb DDR3 2TB Nvidia GTX 970](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NXY21JS) (probably custom built by a company.

I would get the dell, save some money and get an SSD for all computers. I use the [Samsung 850 EVO 250GB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OAJ412U) on my computer. Install the applications on this drive and the media on the 1TB drive.

If you're looking for a more detailed answer I would ask the same question over at http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/31/prebuilt.html

Note: I would also make sure to delete all the bloatware that comes with a the PC that you buy.

Comment: Just be aware that these may not be the best per say at the price range and I suggest getting more opinions but the PCs listed are way more than capable of running any program.